# Android : The use of the ActionBarSherlock library

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

I want to create an application that will target old Android platforms (>= 2.x).

I found the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) that allows building action bars in an ICS style.

But, when I read [its FAQ](http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html), I found that I have to compile my project with the API level 14 (4.0 : ICS) and target the API level 11 in my manifest (3.0 : Honeycomb).

So, my question is : how can I target the 2.x versions with ActionBarSherlock?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a very common question and the answer is relatively simple. Just because you target 4.0 does not mean it will not run on earlier versions. In your manifest you need to add the following:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

As you can see this effectively says you are targeting API level 14 however the minimum API level supported is 2.1 (update 1).

This is all clearly explained in the documentation on the ABS site. If you wish to know more about the `<uses-sdk>` tag then visit http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm comfortable with the Android platform but, as It is written in the FAQ, the first thing we understand is that the `minSdkVersion` should be set to `11`.

Comment: No that's wrong. It says "Targetting API level 11 or newer is required" - notice targeting *not* minSdkVersion. The reason for this is that 11 is when the actionbar is natively supported as stated by - "will cause Android to automatically add the native action bar when run on newer device"

Comment: Brilliant explanation. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, truthfully I got hung up on this a tad at the start.

Comment: @GrahamSmith just curious, how stable have you found ABS on older devices (2.2 for instance)?

Comment: @ajacian81 Interesting question! I have not (yet) has any issues with it on older devices. We test on an old HTC Hero and have not experienced any related issues.

Comment: @GrahamSmith I am `targeting` `18` with a `minSdkVersion` of `10`.  Everything works fine on my `4.x` device, but if I deploy to a `2.3.x` device then the action bar just doesn't show.  I don't see any errors.  Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: @mattblang is your theme set to or inheriting Theme.Sherlock (or one of its counterparts)?

Comment: @GrahamSmith Affirmative, using `Theme.Sherlock.Light`.

Comment: Are you using SherlockFragment and SherlockFragmentActivity?