# Explicit configuration needed to support ICS?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play

I have a relatively new app that I just released and it seems that ICS (Ice Cream Sandwich) users all get the "Your device isn't compatible with this version." error message from Google Play.  The same users are able to install the app when they directly download the apk file.

Do I have to do anything explicit to support ICS users installing the app through Google Play?

My manifest file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dmbstream.android"
    android:installLocation="auto" 
    android:versionCode="7" 
    android:versionName="1.0.7">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10" android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>

    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:name=".DmbstreamApplication">
        <activity android:name=".activity.MainMenuActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.LoginWithTokenActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.ChatActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.ConcertActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.LatestAddedConcertsActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.LatestPerformedConcertsActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.SearchActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.YourFavoritesActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.YourPlaylistsActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.PlaylistActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />

        <activity android:name=".activity.SearchResultsActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".service.DownloadServiceImpl" android:label="DMBStream Service"/>

        <receiver android:name=".receiver.MediaButtonIntentReceiver">
                <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
                </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".receiver.BluetoothIntentReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.a2dp.action.SINK_STATE_CHANGED"/>
                </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".provider.DmbstreamAppWidgetProvider" >
                <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info"/>
        </receiver>

        <provider android:name=".provider.SearchSuggestionProvider"
                                    android:authorities=".provider.SearchSuggestionProvider"/>

        <!-- declare the default searchable Activity for the whole app -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".activity.SearchActivity" />

<!--        <receiver
                android:name="com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
                android:exported="true" >
                <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
                </intent-filter>
        </receiver> -->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any specific configuration necessary for ICS. I don't see anything obviously wrong with your manifest either. Take a look at the Supported Devices section in your Developer Console under your app and see if there's anything obvious there. Also look in the APK files tab, just to verify that API level says 4-16+.

Comment: @kabuko Yep, the APK Files tab says that API level: 4-16+ are supported.

Comment: I'm at a loss then unfortunately... The only thing I can think of that you might try is creating a test app with essentially the same manifest, make sure you see the same problem, then start cutting down optional lines of the manifest to isolate the problem.

Comment: @kabuko Get this... I removed the `<supports-screens />` element and posted a new "test" app.  ICS users could install that fine.  When I made the same change to my "real" app, they still couldn't install it.  I am completely confused now...

Comment: That's baffling... I guess the other thing you can check is again in your dev console, there's a section called supported devices. Click on the show devices link and see if you see anything there that looks interesting. I'm pretty much out of ideas other than that though.

Answer (score 1):

Just Follow Android HIG(Android Human Interface Guidelines)

Android Complete example support all Api levels(tablets & Phones)

- http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `<supports-screens />` element seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10" android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

needs to be at least API level 14:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

[API Level List](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) and [Google Play Filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html) offer more information on the topic.

**EDIT (Based on Comments)**:

You could use:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10" 
          android:maxSdkVersion="15" 
          android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

and get away with it but, as far as I know, it's [not recommended](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max):

> Warning: Declaring this attribute is not recommended. First, there is
>   no need to set the attribute as means of blocking deployment of your
>   application onto new versions of the Android platform as they are
>   released. By design, new versions of the platform are fully
>   backward-compatible. Your application should work properly on new
>   versions, provided it uses only standard APIs and follows development
>   best practices. Second, note that in some cases, declaring the
>   attribute can result in your application being removed from users'
>   devices after a system update to a higher API Level. Most devices on
>   which your application is likely to be installed will receive periodic
>   system updates over the air, so you should consider their effect on
>   your application before setting this attribute.

I guess, if you were to try using `maxSdkVersion`, just **be sure to test** on an Emulator API level 14+ to be sure everything works before opening up to ICS users only to find out it's not working because it did in fact need to be targeted and built out using API 14+ ...

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665059/android-the-use-of-the-actionbarsherlock-library

Comment: So all older apps that target less than 14 will not work on ICS?  Seems faulty, to me...

Comment: From the "Application forward compatibility" section from the API Level List page: "Android applications are generally forward-compatible with new versions of the Android platform."  That being the case, I'm curious why I would have to target v14 to enable ICS support.

Comment: Well, you're right, don't have to use `android:targetSdkVersion="14"` you could use `android:maxSdkVersion="15"` and keep `android:targetSdkVersion="10"` but, as far as I know, it is not recommended.

Comment: maxSdkVersion is not something I care to use.  It seems extremely limiting.  My app runs fine on ICS in the emulator, even when I target v10.  The problem is that Google Play tells people that their device is not compatible.

Comment: Is there any documentation that explicitly states that I have to target v14+ in order to support ICS devices? Otherwise, it seems to me that ICS would basically break compatibility with all previous apps.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html and https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

Comment: @TryTryAgain No, this is wrong. You shouldn't need to specify SDK version 14+. minSdkVersion = 4 should cover API 14. Please read the docs that you linked. Furthermore, maxSdkVersion is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html).

Comment: @kabuko how in the world could minSdkVersion="4" Android 1.6 cover API level 14 Android 4.0? And I stated maxSdkVersion should not be used.

Comment: Minimum of 4 means that any number greater than or equal to 4 works. 14 is greater than 4.